# Add items to custom page

Tags: apex, visualforce

For my app I need the following:

- In standard object Contact add a button "Deals" on layout. It should lead to a new page with all the deals associated with this contact.
- On that new page you should have: Contact info, Today's deals, Total deals and list of all the Deals.

So far I could make a custom button that would lead me to the custom page. But once on that page I have no idea how to get that Contact info(let's say I need Title, Name and Birthdate) and how to get his/her Deals.

Code of that page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Contact" recordsetVar="contacts">
    <h1>Deal Viewer</h1>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:dataTable value="{!contacts}" var="pitem" rowClasses="odd,even">
         <apex:column headerValue="Contact: ">
            <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.name}"/>
         </apex:column>
      </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Right now I get the list of all Contacts, but I still don't know how to only get the one that I need(the one from which layout I clicked "Deals" button).

Comment: Where you plan to set the button? in the `dataTable` one button for each contact record?

Comment: @highfive the button is in Contacts layout, in the Custom buttons section

Comment: If so how you are going to track which contact is selected? I'm assuming you need to load some details of the selected contact upon a **Deals** button clicked

Comment: @highfive that's pretty much the question. I'm still quite new to salesforce(only started last week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured it out.

Instead of using `standardController="Contact"` I used a custom controller. Also, I edited the button so that it passes a contact ID (`https://c.eu3.visual.force.com/apex/deals?id={!Contact.Id}`).

Then I could easily get that ID from my custom controller:

```
contact = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact
           WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

And using this `contact` object I can(should be able to) access all his/her deals.

Hope it might help someone in the future (And I hope it's not a duplicate)